# How can I modify the guest files using the host in VMWare?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware

I want to put Ubuntu Server in my Virtual Machine. I don't know Linux, I want to be able to modify the Linux files using Windows (my host OS). Is this possible using VMWare Player or Workstation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to share a folder in the guest OS, that way you will be able to edit files in shared folder from the windows.